# Google maps keeps disabling Privacy Guard on cyangenmod

Tags: cyanogenmod, privacy, google-maps

This is pretty serious

Rooted with Cm11. Google maps is on sdcard, play services and play store are on system.

I keep seeing google maps privacy guard getting disabled. Once in a while.
Is it possible to disallow this behavior?

There is no point in having PrivacyGuard if every system app can disable it.

Comment: Since you are rooted , converting Maps to user app (TiBu) may be an option of Maps is the culprit. And use apps are not tripping Privacy Guard

Comment: Typo for use apps read  user apps. Of course, this is a workaround not a solution if all system apps are culprits